# nginx http auth request module will only return default error pages

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx as a single point of entry to my entire solution.

my goal is to send some url to be authenticated before continuing.

I have found a module named: `ngx_http_auth_request_module` which suits right in place to solve my problem.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html

i am compiling my nginx like this: `./configure --with-http_auth_request_module`

my code looks like this:

```
http {

    server {
        listen       8080 default_server;

        server_name _;

        location /api {
            auth_request /auth;
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:8000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location = /auth {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/auth/user;
            proxy_pass_request_body off;
            proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
            proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        }

    }
}
```

my problem is that if my server returns and error, like `401`, then a default page gets shown. what i want is to be able to return the json that was returned from my authentication service. this is useless without this. what is the point of showing just a generic `401` page? i want to return my proxied json response.

please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

auth_request is just for authentication. This little hack should work for you

```
error_page 401 /auth;
```

After auth error it'll go to /auth location again, this time as ordinary request.

Comment: Using this will also affect the underling application. Once it responds with a 401 status you'll see /auth as the error message. This obscures the context. Being in a login screen within the application itself, getting a 401, seeing the message of the "/auth" route. Those two are not very related and misleading.